# need to adjust tinymce when using bbcode plugin with quotes

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

I need help with TinyMCE Editor and it's BBCode plugin with Quotes.

All I want is for when I select text to be quoted to have all highlighted text wrapped in a single div.

The default quote style seems to give every line highlighted it's own span tag which is horrible and makes every line a new quote rather than all one block.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I fear this is not possible out of the box. Problem here is that tinymce has a certain prcedure to style text (usualy spans). And there is no easy way to adjust that. For this you would need to fiddle around with the tinymce core class `Formatter.js` , which i do not advise.

Comment: I guess i need a completely separate plugin then for dealing with quotes. What a pain!